# Webview userAgent Prop breaks onShouldLoadWithRequest event request object

Tags: react-native, webview, powerbi, download, user-agent

I am working on a project using a react native webview that renders a web page that uses Power bi and allows the user to download any Power Bi report (not static downloads but progressive). Currently we had to add the userAgent props to the react native webview for a secondary issue. Before adding the userAgent props, i was getting the full data of the report inside the onShouldLoadWithRequest request.url like this `"blob:attachement/file; base64 data-here"`. I then used the data to save the report.

After adding the userAgent props, the data coming to onShouldLoadWithRequest in the request object is now a blob url that looks like `blob:https://www.ursite.com/349d9d9ssc99a9dc9v9h9e9s9w99sa`. When i try to download the blob url i get a simple small (3K) html page, nothing of it is the data for the report.

Is there a reason that by adding userAgent, onShouldLoadWithRequest is changing the data coming in the request object from full data to a blob url? Has anyone face this issue and if so how did you fix it (we can't just remove the userAgent props because it will break the app in a different way). Also Power Bi download is not static so the onFileDownload event does not trigger. I have tried all the events from the webview to see if i get the data, i tried also to download the blob using react-native-blob-util and no success. Thank you in advance for your suggestions.